# Track the recently Modified Sites in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, last-modified-date

I am working on the console where I need to prepare the list of all the Sites in the tenant which were modified in last 24 hours or given timeframe.

I tried to use the [Tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn159172(v=office.15)) method which returns the LastContentModifiedDate but this property is getting updated even if the user just visits the site.

Is there any other property available using CSOM which can be used to recently updated/modified sites?